# How replace the first few layers of a pre-trained neural network in keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use the MobileNet model available in keras. But my input image has 5 channels (as opposed to the 3 channels the MobileNet model supports). I'm trying to replace the existing Input layer and the first convolution operation to preserve the model consistency and make use of the pre-trained weights.

I've tried to pop the first 3 layers of MobileNet and replace them with custom layers, but it wouldn't work.

```
model = MobileNet(include_top=False, pooling='avg')
model.layers.pop(0)
model.layers.pop(0)
model.layers.pop(0)

inp = Input(shape=(None,None,5))
conv = Conv2D(32,1,strides=(2,2))(inp)

model = model(conv)

model.summary()
```

I've tried something like the above, but it's throwing me

```
ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 
32 != 3
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should rebuild the complete model (freezing any layers you like) and then set the initial weights from the preloaded one. `model.layers.pop` is not effective as it doesn't modify the underlying graph.

Comment: So the only wait to do this would be to create the model myself and load the weights for all the layers except the ones i modified ? Is there any other way I could modify the underlying graph ?

Comment: It should be possible but it's probably much easier to build a new model by iterating over the layers and setting the initial weights.